# How can I register push notifications without azure for UWP?

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp

I would like to implement push notifications one of my UWP application. 
I found a lots of specifications on msdn.com, but they are only tells me why should I use the push notification service and I may need to create some certification for it. When I log in the dev center and click on Push notifications menu it show me this outdated page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx

I tried to check the newest version but noting found.

Also I don't understood how can I create that certification I need to upload or how can I send those notifications to the phones. Is there any complete tutorial for this that is not outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications in UWP are not dependent on Azure Notification Hubs. You can use any 3rd party push notification service of your choosing.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) is the main documentation on how push works in general.

I know you said you don't want to use Azure, but you can find some great documentation on how to implement it using Azure Notification Hubs [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/). You can just look at the actual UWP implementations and use any other backend.